# which maven Archetype to use for standalone java project

Tags: java, maven

I am planing to create a maven project to develop a batch program that can be scheduled in windows system.

here is my requirement.

1. there is no database interaction
2. need to read xml data and send email using log4j
3. build jar of the java project.
4. thinking to use spring OXM with JAXB
5. need to create .bat file so that it will be schedule using windows task manager for to run it every 2 hours.
   so I am planing to have a project such that the data configured in xml will be outside of my jar.

please advise which Archetype to select and help on my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [maven-archetype-simple](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-simple/) to create simple jar project

Comment: i could not find it. I have "A simple J2EE Java application" and scala -archetype-simple only in case of simple

Answer (score 0):

You should run the following command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, then while creating a maven project from wizard it will give one check box on top which says "Create a simple maven project.........". You can select this if you are confuse with what type to select

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [java-archetype](https://github.com/oliviercailloux/java-archetype): it has reasonable defaults for quickly starting a Java project following best practices. It can be considered a modern successor of maven-archetype-quickstart.

Disclaimer: I am the author.